# Ошибка при востановлении дампа MySQL

Tags: linux, mysql

Пытаюсь перенести базу mysql с виндового серва на Linux Arch.

На виндовом серве MySQL 5.0.18. На Linux Mysql 5.5.21

при восстановлении произошла следующая ошибка

> `(232572, 1):You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 232572Хотите проигнорировать ошибку и продолжить?

Вот кусок дампа со строкой ошибки, строку 232572 пометил

```
-- Описание для триггера AfterInsertInBOMsAndAD    --
CREATE TRIGGER AfterInsertInBOMsAndAD
AFTER INSERT
ON bomsandad
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  Declare MRWR Varchar (24);
  Set MRWR=UCase(new.ManRefNumber);
  If (RIGHT(MRWR,1)>='A') AND (RIGHT(MRWR,1)<='Z') then
    Set MRWR=Left(MRWR,Length(Mrwr)-1);
  End If;
  If NOT ((MRWR Is Null) OR (MRWR='')) Then
  INSERT HIGH_PRIORITY
     INTO ieconstructors.revisions(ManRefNumwoRev,RevisionName,WriteDate,Writer,Description)
**232571**
VALUES (MRWR,new.Revision,new.DevelopmentDate,new.DeveloperId,_cp1251'
**232572**
$$
--
-- Описание для триггера AfterDeleteFromDrawingNumbers    --
CREATE TRIGGER AfterDeleteFromDrawingNumbers
AFTER DELETE
ON drawingnumbers
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  Declare done INT Default 0;
  Declare flag INT Default 0;
  Declare rev  VARCHAR(1);
  Declare MRNWR VARCHAR(24);
  Declare CURSOR1 CURSOR
     FOR SELECT RevisionName FROM `ieconstructors`.`revisions`
       WHERE `ieconstructors`.`revisions`.ManRefNumwoRev=CONVERT(MRNWR USING cp1251);
  Declare CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE "02000" SET done = 1;
        Set MRNWR=old.ManRefNumber;
  If ((MRNWR is not null) and (MRNWR<>"") and (old.Revision is not null) and (old.Revision<>"")) then
    If (CONVERT(Right(MRNWR,1) USING cp1251)=old.Revision) then
    begin
      Set MRNWR=Left(MRNWR,length(MRNWR)-1);
      Open CURSOR1;
        REPEAT
          FETCH CURSOR1 INTO rev;
          IF NOT done THEN
            If CONVERT(rev USING cp1251)>old.Revision then
              Set flag=1;
            End If;
          END IF;
        UNTIL done END REPEAT;
      Close CURSOR1;
      If not flag then
         Delete Low_Priority Quick
          From `ieconstructors`.`revisions`
          Where `RevisionName`=old.Revision AND `ManRefNumwoRev`=CONVERT(MRNWR USING cp1251);
      End if;
    end;
    End if;
  End if;
END
$$
--
-- Описание для триггера AfterInsertInDrawingNumbers
--    CREATE TRIGGER AfterInsertInDrawingNumbers
AFTER INSERT
ON drawingnumbers
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  Declare MRWR Varchar (24);
  Set MRWR=UCase(new.ManRefNumber);
  If (RIGHT(MRWR,1)>="A") AND (RIGHT(MRWR,1)<="Z") then
    Set MRWR=Left(MRWR,Length(Mrwr)-1);
  End If;
  If NOT ((MRWR Is Null) OR (MRWR="")) Then
  INSERT HIGH_PRIORITY
     INTO ieconstructors.revisions(ManRefNumwoRev,RevisionName,WriteDate,Writer,Description)
    VALUES (MRWR,new.Revision,new.DeveloperDate,new.Developer,_cp1251'
$$
    DELIMITER ;
 --
 -- Включение внешних ключей
 --
 /*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
```

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, что триггеры неверно определены. В обоих триггерах *AfterInsertInBOMsAndAD* и *AfterInsertInDrawingNumbers* отсутствуют завершающие инструкции. Рекомендую посмотреть DDL этих двух триггеров на виндовом сервере. Ясно видно, что как минимум отсутствует закрывающая скобка в INSERT, вероятно, лишний апостроф после _cp1251, оператор End If; и в конце триггера завершающее END

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте скопировать файлы базы в директорий /var/lib/mysql/mysql  .frm .MYD  .MYI